# Can't access my WordPress dashboard after I login

Tags: wordpress

When I click on it, nothing happens - no error message, no change url, it just refreshes the home page.
In fact, if I logout by clearing my history, I can't even access the WordPress login page. To get to that I have to use mysite/wp-login.php
So now that's I'm logged in, I can see the dashboard link but when I click on it, nothing happens.

I haven't been working on this wite for weeks. It's unlikely I have broken anything. Maybe an update has caused a conflict - but i have a number of other very similar sites that don't have this issue. I suspect I've been hacked.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Cleared history and reboot
2. Tried it on a different browser
3. backup and then remove htaccess file (didn't fix the problem)
4. Rename wp-content/plugins folder through file manager in my control panel to disable plugins (didn't fix the problem)
5. Went into my database in cpanel, check the user and confirmed they have full access rights. Not sure if this translate to access rights to the dashboard)
6. Went into my database in cpanel and created a new user (was unable to login - unsure what the login creds are and only have 3 shots)
7. I went into the phpMyAdmin and had a look at the database;

In table wp-users;

The same two users who should be there, are there. I added a new user and logged in as new user - this didn't fix the issue which is not a surprise because this doesn't seem like a login issue, more a privelages issue.

8. In table wp_usermeta;

wp_capabilities = a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
wp_user_level = 10

So my user levels look correct. This is probably not privelage issue, or a hack.

9. Still in table wp_usermeta;

Deleted the session tokens record in case i had a heap of concurrent open sessions.

Didn't work.

10. Went into my control panel and then file manager and noticed a txt file called error_log

PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/siteo1/public_html/aindex.php on line 3

11. Googled it and discovered this is most likely because of old wordpress. Downloaded latest wordpress, renamed wp-admin and wp-includes in my file manger to something else. Uploaded the same folders from the downloaded new version.

Didn't work.

I'm almost out of ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Rigid.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I have the answer.

I was hacked. Hackers put a .htaccess file in my wp-admin folder that denied all access and overrode the one I had in the root.